# Recommended web technology for the WPF developer?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm planning to develop an information system but the point is, I'm better at using WPF than ASP.NET. I don't see anything that WPF can't do on the web against ASP.NET besides its built in Membership class, etc? Security? I'm not pretty sure. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ASP.NET site can run on almost any computer including non-Windows platforms, usually without requiring installing any extra software - just using the standard web browser. WPF (Silverlight) allows a richer interface but it may require an extra installation for your clients and it may not work correctly on all platforms.

There is [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) but so far only Silverlight 2 is implemented.

Comment: Moonlight is a good project but it needs to support post silverlight 2 version

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net).

Silverlight uses a very similar syntax as WPF (xaml) and its data-binding and presentation-layer is almost identical to WPF.
BTW, Silverlight also offers a 'built-in' membership provider and security, read [this](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Leveraging-the-ASP.NET-Membership-in-Silverlight.aspx) for more details.

The question should whom are you developing this site for, or more precisely, whom is this site aimed to serve.
If this site is for a company etc. with a known crowd that you can tell all of them to use Silverlight (i.e. you know that they won't have a problem to install the Silverlight plugin which is very light, and is multi-platform targeted), look no further and use Silverlight.
If the site is aimed for the broad public and is aimed to interest external people, I am doubting if new users will want to install the plugin just "to check" what's in that new site.